# Android: Use callback method of AsyncTask class to change Activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, task

I use AsyncTask to perform some data load over http requests in background. The http request use a session variable. This variable can become invalid and the http request will return an error.
In this case the user have to relogin.

So, can I just use something like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(IData data) {
            //
            // !!On Error data object is null!!
            // 
    if (mCallback != null) {
        mCallback.onTaskComplete(data);
    }
}
```

And in the Activity which implements the Callback interface I just check if the data object is null and change the Activity to the "MainActivity" Login form.

```
    public void onTaskComplete(IData data) {
    if (data == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ReadDataActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        deleteCurrentSavedSession();
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
           // Do something with the data
        }
    }
```

Is this a bad idea? Should I better use `ExecutorService` and execute it as a "normal" thread which checks if the session is still valid?

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
executor.execute(sessionCheckWorker);
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

}
// Wait until session check task is finished and decide which Activity to load
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for ExecutorService. It is meant specifically for such timer related tasks. I would also suggest you to use handlers in combination with ExecutorService, since handlers give you more control over such tasks as compared to Asynctask.